# Numbers with hyphen separator (123456789 to 123-45-6789)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number like 123456789. I want to display the number like 123-45-6789. How can I achieve this in asp.net with C#?

This number stored in varchar format in database. I just want to display the number in label with proper hypen.

Comment: Do you have a pattern for this? I don't see any on this one.

Comment: No. How can I achieve this using pattern?

Comment: You misunderstand me. For example; if your number will be `987654321`, you result should be `987-65-4321` ? You want to separate them always as `3 digit - 2 digit - 4 digit`?

Comment: Yes. Always 3 digit - 2 digit - 4 digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use basic number-formatting:

```
yourNumber.ToString("###-##-####");
```

**Update:**

Ok, if you already have it as a string, you can split it and add hyphens:

```
var result = str.Substring(0,3) + "-" 
                + str.Substring(3,2) + "-" 
                + str.Substring(5);
```

...or on secont thought, perhaps String.Insert() is simpler:

```
// insert "-" after position 3, then after position 6 in the returned string.
result = str.Insert(3, "-").Insert(6, "-");
```

Comment: It shows error, because the num is already string.The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
Regex.Replace("987654321", @"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use.

`var outputString = yourString.Insert(3,"-").Insert(6,"-");`